# How to store big string mostly containing nbsp and br (line break)s in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I want to store strings in a TEXT column in MySQL.

The strings mostly consists of `&nbsp;` which is the main problem, MySQL (and CodeIgniter) converts them to spaces. And they are important because the string only makes sense with the appropriate amount of spacing.

I considered converting `&nbsp;` to `<div class='whitespace'></div>` so that I can style with CSS, but it will make the MySQL column bigger.

So how can I efficiently store such a string in MySQL database?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: escape the stuff and go ahead or use html entities encode/decode.

Comment: Wait. What are you using for your table? What encoding? I've tried to insert some text with &nbsp; and it doesn't convert.

Comment: Does it convert to space with code 0x20 or 0xa0?

Comment: @AshrafSamhouri I guess PHP was converting it. htmlentities solved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use htmlentities (http://www.php.net/htmlentities)

```
echo htmlentities('Hi&nbsp;there');
// outputs 
// Hi&nbsp;there

echo 'Hi&nbsp;there';
// outputs
// Hi there
```

If you want to decode instead (the reverse) you can use html_entity_decode().
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: And what about `<br>` tags? one of htmlentities or base64_decode is rmeoving br's but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Hi Cengiz, Output of echo htmlentities('Hi&nbsp;<br>there'); is "Hi&nbsp;<br>there"... htmlentities will not remove <br> tags. However please make sure that your decoding orders are correct i.e. if you are encoding using base64_encode(htmlentities(data)) then your decoding should be html_entity_decode(base64_decode(encoded_data))

Comment: example: echo $converted_data = base64_encode(htmlentities('Hi&nbsp;<br>there')); echo "<br>"; echo $original_html_data = base64_decode($converted_data);

Answer (score 2):

Consider to`base64_encode` the data before inserting it in mysql.

```
$bigstr = base64_encode($bigstr);
/* insert to database */
```

Remember to `base64_decode` when fetching the string back.

Comment: Great. This reduces the size right? 

This solution worked for me : `base64_encode(html_entities($html))`; Thanks again !

Comment: This will increase the size of information stored to the database. Try it yourself with an "UTF-8 string length & byte counter". '&nbsp;' (6 bytes), the same in base64 'Jm5ic3A7' (8 bytes). In case of the unicode-character U+00A0 (2 bytes) in base64 'wqA=' (4 bytes), '♥' (3 bytes) in base64 '4pml' (4 bytes). Maybe there are reasons you can and should use this idea, but be careful and check your db size.

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions:

```php
function getRawString($str) {
    return strtr($str, array("&nbsp;" => " "));
}

function getDisplayString($str) {
    return strtr($str, array(" " => "&nbsp;"));
}
```

Store the raw string in the database:

```php
$str = file_get_contents('html_file.html');
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (my_text) VALUES ('" . getRawString($str) . "')";
// Execute query...
```

Fetch it from the database and display it:

```php
echo getDisplayString($strFromDB);
```

Comment: Nope, I already got the `&nbsp;`'d version from an HTML file, I just want to store it correctly and efficiently.

Comment: Edited the answer to match your needs.